# Unable to bind my scope variable into ng-src directive in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to get the image url from s3 bucket in my page I got the url in angularjs file but I am unable to bind the url in ng-src directive

This is my view

```html
<img ng-src="{{imgData}}" />
```

This is my angularjs controller:

```js
app.controller('Sample', function($scope) {
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: ''
  });
  AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
  $scope.s3Url = '';
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
      Bucket: 'mybucketname',
      Prefix: 'UPLOADS'
    }
  });
  bucket.listObjects(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data.Contents[1]);
      $scope.imgData = $scope.s3Url + data.Contents[1].Key;
      console.log($scope.imgData);
    }
  });
});
```

I got the exact url in the console

Comment: Are you sure it's not binding or it can't find the image?

Comment: yes its not binding I got the url from console I paste the url in src its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Assumes that you're getting the imageData correctly and try the following.

```
<img ng-src="'{{imgData}}'" />
```